# Dynamicy NAV Comma-aligned decimal numbers

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, reportbuilder, navision

I'm trying to align decimal numbers in Microsoft Dynamics NAV, ie. in Report builder by comma. It should look something like this:

```
 21,456
  3,33
178,7564
```

As you can see I want to do it no matter how many decimal places I have.

Does anyone knows how to do it trough Navision or Report Builder?
I would be very grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

By default NAV prints something like this

[image]

You need to change a property of you `textbox` to print in your format, set `TextAling` property in **Center**.

[image]

Save changes an execute the report. ***You can see this***

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work for me

Comment: That strange, there are the proofs that it works, in what version of NAV are you trying? If 2013 or later tries to restart the service, then try again.

Comment: @DraganaOstopanj what version of nav are you using?

Comment: @AFR I'm using NAV 2013.

Comment: This test is also in **NAV 2013**, Surely you have a table in report viewer with a repeater, there you have a textbox with your variable "number" this textbox you  must set **textAlign = Center**